Configure Spring Boot global exception handling without disabling autoconfigure
I have a complex Spring Boot (version 2.7.18) application that I need to capture all errors and exceptions and return a generic error message to the user. The error/exception will be logged for research but the user will only receive the generic message “…your request could not be completed…”.  I believe a ResponseEntityExceptionHandler can be configured to catch all errors/exceptions. Please correct this first statement if I am wrong.
Spring annotations and Spring Boot defaults enables my application to serve a single page web application (Angular) to the browser. After the web application is bootstrapped in the browser, my Spring application also hosts REST endpoints and hosts a Websocket server which are both utilized only by the web application.
I need to handle 400 Bad Requests, 500 Internal Server Errors, as well as exceptions thrown from my REST endpoints. I was able to solve the last case, REST exceptions from my endpoints by implementing a HandlerExceptionResolver.
For all of the other errors and exceptions I have tried to implement the solution presented in this post Spring Boot REST service exception handling.  However, when I try to implement that solution this breaks my application.
When I add @EnableWebMvc to the @ControllerAdvice class my web application will not load in the browser and any link that I try to “Get” just forwards me to the configured “/error” mapping. For example a Get to “index.html” that used to work now fails.
Another issue, (even without added @EnableWebMvc) is if I added the recommended changes to application.properties which are:
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false
This change causes any Get to return the exception:
org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler found for GET /index.html
The solution as presented clearly warns that using @EnableWebMvc will disable the autoconfiguration of Spring Boot.
I need one of two solutions

Configure a ResponseEntityExceptionHandler  along with all of the Spring Boot defaults?
Include @EnableWebMvc, but configure the Spring Boot defaults.

Here is my attempt to handle Throwable, but these methods are never called for 500 or 400 errors:
    @ControllerAdvice
class ExceptionHandlerCtrl extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    ResponseEntity<Object> handleControllerException(Throwable ex) {
        Map<String,String> responseBody = new HashMap<>();
        responseBody.put("path","newPath");
        responseBody.put("message","The URL you have reached is not in service at this time (404).");
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(responseBody,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        Map<String,String> responseBody = new HashMap<>();
        responseBody.put("path",request.getContextPath());
        responseBody.put("message","The URL you have reached is not in service at this time (404).");
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(responseBody,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}


Just add a ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and the default one will backoff. Don't add @EnableWebMvc as that will disable the whole web auto-configuration from Spring Boot.

Deinum, thanks for the help.  I have added ResponseEntityExceptionHandler but the handler methods are not being called for 500 Internal Service errors or 400 Invalid Requests. These are still returned to the client. Please let me know if you have additional suggestions.

The ResponseEntityExceptionHandler will handle specific exceptions, if you don't override those nothing will happen. YOu don't really need a ResponseEntityExceptionHandler but rather a class annotated with @ControllerAdvice which has an @ExceptionHandler and handle all Exception and handle it.

Deinum, thanks again.  I have created a ResponseEntityExceptionHandler that is handling Throwable.  It was just never called for 500 or 400 errors.  As most have found in the other thread if you do not include @EnableWebMvc Spring does not setup the necessary callbacks.  I am trying to figure out how to setup that callback without EnableWebMvc because that disables the autoconfigure.  I will add my class above.  Please let me know if you see anything wrong with it.

Please read... You don't need the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler you only need a class with @ControllerAdvice and an @ExceptionHandler method. Spring Boot automatically includes @EnableWebMvc so you don't need to. The method you add must be annotated with @ExceptionHandler if you don't it does nothing. There are no 500/400 errors only exceptions which are handled by the generic method from the super class.

I need to catch 400 and 500 errors.  Are you saying I cannot do that with an ExceptionHandler.  If I cannot do that with an ExceptionHandler then this is not the solution I need.  As I stated above I need to catch all of the 400 and 500 errors and return an error message and a 200 response code to the user.

Again there are no 400 and 500 errors there are only exceptions, the thing is called an ExceptionHandler for a reason. Those exceptions are the thiings that get converted to 400/500 or whatever the exception corresponds to are getting converted. Also always returning http 200 is considered a bad practice.

I do appreciate your help.  My requirements are to not return 400/500 errors to clients especially with stack traces which make my app look unprofessional and can provide insight to the technologies used which may be exploited.  I will have to search for a different answer.  I expect I will need to dig into the Spring code for this since no solution presented or that I can find seems to work for me.  Regards.

You don't need to dig into spring code you need 1 handler for all exceptions if that is what you want, just don't extend the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler as mentioned multiple times before.
